# How are PHP versions counted?

Tags: php

Silly question; I've been wanting to use Doctrine with CodeIgniter on a personal portfolio site, but Doctrine indicates that it needs PHP 5.2.3 or greater. I submitted a ticket to my hosting provider asking when they would be upgrading PHP (they were running 5.2.1). I just got a message saying they've updated to 5.2.12, which is greater than 5.2.3.

Is this true? I've looked at the php.net downloads page but it's hard to tell which is more recent. I think I may be misinterpreting 5.2.12 as 5.2.1.2 - obviously 12 is higher than 3, but is that how the versions are numbered?

Comment: 5.2.12 is newer than 5.2.1.2. Read on [Software versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning).

Comment: major version dot minor version dot patch version, thats basically all the magic to know about. and yes 5.2.12 is greater than 5.2.3 :)

Comment: Why would you add a decimal point that doesn't exist? I guess it would be slightly more clear if they were zero padding the single digit numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version `5.2.12` means:

- Major version: 5
- Minor version: 2
- Release version: 12
- Extra version: *(empty)*
- Full version name: 5.2.12
- Version ID: 50212

...and yes 5.2.12 is newer than 5.2.3 since 12 is higher than 3.

Answer (score 0):

What do you know, that's [indeed true](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php)! Didn't know that myself, I was under the impression they were working with single numbers (i.e. `5.2.1.7`, which also is a valid numbering scheme especially in the Unix/Linux world.)

> **Version 5.2.17**
>
> 06-Jan-2011
>
> **Version 5.2.16**
>
> 16-Dec-2010
>
> **Version 5.2.15**
>
> 08-Dec-2010

Comment: lol, their changelog is wrong. 5.2.17 wasn't released until January **2011** (not 2010 as listed on their site).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might find the [`version_compare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) function useful

Answer (score 0):

See the [changelog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) to understand the history.

Comment: Unfortunately, the changelog only adds to the confusion as it's currently incorrect (as of this writing it states that 5.2.17 was released before 5.2.16).

Comment: @webbiedave: Indeed it does!  Although I'm sure they really meant "2011".  Neverthless, I think one can rely on the top-to-bottom chronological ordering.